# BlackJack Java: Exception Error

Tags: java, runtime-error, blackjack

I am having an error with my BlackJack Java game. The error is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.keegan.game.blackjack.Deck.createDeck(Deck.java:48)

    at com.keegan.game.blackjack.Deck.<init>(Deck.java:33)`

And I am pretty clueless as to what the problem is in this code. Can anyone help me understand what the error is telling me that is wrong?

Here is the code for `Deck.java`:

```
public class Deck {

private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

private List<Card> cardUsed = new ArrayList<Card>();
Card c = new Card(null, null, null, 0);

public Deck(int numCards) {
    this.createDeck(numCards, 4, null);
}

private void createDeck(int numCards, int numSuits, String[] cardRanks) {
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    cardUsed = new ArrayList<Card>();
    if ((numCards % numSuits) > 0) return;
    for (int i=0; i < numSuits; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j <= (numCards / numSuits); j++) {
            deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), cardRanks[j-1], cardRanks, j));
        }
    }
}

public Card dealCard( ) {

    Card dealtCard = null;
    if (deck.size() == 0){
        deck.addAll(cardUsed);
        this.shuffle();
        cardUsed = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    dealtCard = deck.get(0);
    deck.remove(0);
    cardUsed.add(dealtCard);

    return dealtCard;
}

public void shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
}

public ArrayList<Card> getDeck() {
    return deck;
}

public void setDeck(ArrayList<Card> deck) {
    this.deck = deck;
}
public int getNumUsedCards() {
    return cardUsed.size();
}

public List<Card> getCardUsed() {
    return cardUsed;
}

public void setCardUsed(List<Card> cardUsed) {
    this.cardUsed = cardUsed;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the line 48 that is refered to in the exception?

Comment: This line: `deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), cardRanks[j-1], cardRanks, j));`

Comment: Did you look into what NullPointerException means first?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes it calls an instance of null, I have no clue how to get around that though since those are the parameters for some classes.

Comment: @DarkZal: Well it's not really "calls an instance of null" - that doesn't really make sense as a concept. But fundamentally if it's inappropriate for your method to receive a null reference, you should make sure it doesn't happen. Have you identified *which* value is null, exactly? You should learn how to diagnose this yourself.

Comment: @DarkZal What do you mean "for some classes"? Classes that extend Class Deck?

Comment: @JonSkeet The value that is null is String cardRank which is intialized as null in my `Card.java` class. But that cardRank doesn't need a value to it so when the `Card` class parameters have null in it, it doesn't run.

Comment: @DarkZal: That seems unlikely to be the problem, given that the line you mentioned doesn't refer to `cardRank` at all. Look for another null value.

Comment: @DarkZal If class Deck might not need String[] cardRank you need to make sure you actually tell that to class Deck, at present it is assuming cardRank is fine and just using it

Comment: @RichardTingle: Well it needs the cardRank so the deck knows that the card has a value and a suit to it when it creates the new deck of cards.

Comment: Ok, so when is it not needed? It sounds like cardRank is always needed, in which case it shouldn't be null

Comment: That's what is confusing me. The `String[] cardRanks` has a value already assigned to it in the `Card` class. I changed it from null to:   `private String[] cardRanks = new String[] {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"} ;`

Comment: If cardRank already exists why are you re-entering it in your constructor? You're entering a big null in the Card constructor. If cardRanks is already set within the card internally why would you additionally pass it in the constructor

Comment: Just because a class has a variable as a field it **does not** need to be in the constructor. Especially if its set internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a `null` array

```
this.createDeck(numCards, 4, null);
```

and later accessing it as `cardRanks[j-1]` in your statement

```
deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), cardRanks[j-1], cardRanks, j));
```

***EDIT** :*
What you probably need is to create your `Deck` as

```
this.createDeck(numCards, 4);
```

and adding the `Card` as

```
deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), j));
```

since, `String[] cardRanks` is already initialized in your `Card` class. And, design-wise it's correct because `Deck` shouldn't have to know about card ranks. `Card` should encapsulate it and maybe *implements Comparable* as well.

Comment: Does the null value make it to where it won't compile at run-time then?

Comment: Yes, it probably does. The stack trace `...Deck.createDeck(Deck.java:48)` shows you the line number to match. You can verify it.

Comment: Null (more or less) means points to nothing. If you can construct a sentence where "nothing" fits then null will be fine (eg passes nothing, is nothing etc) but sentences like "The j-1 element of nothing" make no sense so the exception is raised

Comment: Okay, I think that makes more sense then. How do I go about fixing the variable String cardRank then? It's set as null since it doesn't need a value assigned to it.

Comment: At present your class very much does need it all the time because createDeck uses it. You need to in some way express the not needing it (eg check if its null) and  **if its not needed don't use it**

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an array of empty strings? remember the array is the "holder" and is what you're passing, the one holder holds many Strings (which may or may not be null themselves

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I tried that line of code you posted and it still wants me to pass null into it. So I entered the code `deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), j));`   and it puts in two null's:  `deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), null, null, j));`

Comment: Nevermind! Thank you that fixed it. I just commented out the line of code for the Card class to get the value, deleted the getters and setters and now it generates the cards without error.

Comment: @DarkZal You need to think your design through. Richard has shared really good pointers. Currently, you're focussing on just avoiding the errors but I think a re-factoring of classes is in order.

Comment: @DarkZal I'm glad you got it working but please do take Richard's comments on board.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: I will take his advice, I'm going to have to modify my `Card` class now to make it run as I want it to again.

Answer (score 1):

In you constructor you have passed null as a variable

```
public Deck(int numCards) {
    this.createDeck(numCards, 4, null);
}
```

within your method createDeck you then try to use that variable

```
private void createDeck(int numCards, int numSuits, String[] cardRanks) { //<---cardRanks is null at this point
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    cardUsed = new ArrayList<Card>();
    if ((numCards % numSuits) > 0) return;
    for (int i=0; i < numSuits; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j <= (numCards / numSuits); j++) {
            deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), cardRanks[j-1], cardRanks, j)); 
        }
    }
}
```

When you write `cardRanks[j-1]` you are trying to access the "inside" of cardRanks. If cardRanks is null, i.e. doesn't exist, then it can't access the inside and a `NullPointerException` is its only option. Java understandably complains.

In english what you are telling the program to do (when cardRanks is null) is to take the j-1 element of 'nothing'. This clearly is meaningless and a `NullPointerException` is how the compiler tells you

**Creating arrays of strings that are not null**

```
String[] stringArray=new String[10]; //creates an array big enough to hold 10 Strings
```

At present the stringArray holds 10 nulls

```
stringArray[0]="hi"; //enter first element
stringArray[1]="hi again"; //enter second element
stringArray[2]=""; //empty string is not the same as null
```

Now the first 3 elements are non null, the remaining 7 remain null

you could of course create your strings in a loop or in any way you see fit

**Creating a class that doesn't need to take its fields in a constructor**

```
public class SomeClass {
    String[] someStringArray={"hello", "i'm just fine as I am"}; //creates an array of strings, 2 entries

    int someNumber;

    public SomeClass(int someNumber){
        //this constructor leaves someStringArray alone, its fine as it is
        this.someNumber=someNumber;

    }

    public SomeClass(int someNumber,String[] someStringArray){
        //this constructor changes someStringArray
        this.someNumber=someNumber;
        this.someStringArray=someStringArray;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to initialize a variable without it being assigned as null? Because the String doesn't have a value.

Comment: @DarkZal If you might not need a variable then when you potentially use it you need to check if its null and if it is not use it (this isn't great practice though).

Comment: Its also worth noting its not the string thats null its the **array of strings** thats null

Comment: @DarkZal We were talking about constructors taking fields (but null if they're fine as is), see my edit to see how the constructor doesn't have to take a field at all

Answer (score 0):

```
deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), cardRanks[j-1], cardRanks, j));
```

in this line the cardRanks is null. As you called the method as

```
this.createDeck(numCards, 4, null);
```

You can't access a element  of null array (:p)